# vpn error occurring when trying to connect to a server

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, pptp

I am running windows 7 and at my workplace I have created a PPTP dial-up connection so I can connect back to my workplace but I persistently receive a 807 error:

"The connection between your computer and the VPN server was interrupted..."

Comment: Do you manage the VPN server/device at work? Firewall at work?  If there is an IT department, what do they report?  A error code 807 typically is either the client or the server is behind a NAT device and does not pass through GRE protocol 47 (note this is not PORT 47). If GRE protocol 47 isn't passed through the NAT device you'll get Error807. you'll also get 807 if port 1723 isn't forwarded from the NAT device to the VPN server if the server is behind a NAT device

Comment: Btw. PPTP is horribly insecure and can be broken in less than 24h using Cloudcracker

Comment: If you're based in the UK then VirginMedia's router blocks PPTP by default, but you can resolve this by changing a setting in the router ("PPTP Passthrough"). Your equipment (regardless of ISP) may also be doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by:

1) Right clicking the VPN connection.  Select Properties.

2) Click Security tab.  Make sure Type of VPN is set for Automatic (mine was set for PPTP)

This resolved my issue.  Hopefully it will yours.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps could help you to diagnose and resolve error 807:

1-Check out if you are using the correct Hostname or IP address.

2-Make sure that you internet connection is working properly, if not then reset the adapter or modem, as the case may be.

3-Ping the VPN server to ensure it is available. For this, click “Run” after clicking the “Start” button on the windows screen. Type “Ping” followed by the name of your VPN server or IP address. Press enter. You will come instantly come to know if the server is working or not, in the resulting DOS screen.

4-Confirm your computer's firewall settings are still configured to permit traffic to and from your VPN. As you are using PPTP protocol, TCP Port 1723 and GRE Protocol 47 must be opened/enabled.

5-If any of the antivirus installed at your system is causing the problems in VPN connection than remove it or alternatively, add the the IP of remote client in its configuration settings.

6-If you are able to connect to VPN from your desktop but not from your laptop, it could be probably due to security software such as Microsoft OneCare that is quite capable of blocking GRE, uninstall it and check out the results.

7-If the problem still exists, make a request for VPN server security certificate verification.

hopefully it will work

Answer (score 0):

VPN Error 807 is a common VPN Error which may occur due to following reasons:

- Antivirus or firewall is blocking your connection.
- overload on server.
- Slow internet.

You can follow these simple solutions to fix VPN Error 807

- Disable Antivirus and Firewall while creating vpn connection.
- Make double sure that your VPN IP Address, Username and Password are 
  correctly entered.
- Clear history and cookies and Registry also.
- Set VPN Connection Type to PPTP.
  I found these solutions while searching for this error. [Click Here](http://www.itrickbuzz.com/vpn-error-807-windows-7-8-8-1/) to know more about these solutions.
  Hope this helps.

Comment: "clear the registry"?  Can you elaborate?